# Sort three dimensional numpy array with two axes sorting constraints

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, numpy

I have a three dimensional numpy array which I would like to sort.

An example of the array is given by:

```
arr = numpy.array([[4., 5., .1], [-2., 5., .3], [-1., -3., .2], [5, -4, .1], [2., 2., .25], [-2., 0., .1], [-1.5, 0., .1], [1., -3., .1], [-2., 8, .1]])
```

Lets for convenience call the three dimensions `x`, `y`, and `z`, respectively. I would like to sort my array based on the value of `y` in decreasing order. I know I can do this by

```
arr[arr[:, 1].argsort()[::-1]]
```

However, the second constraint is that for multiple occurrences of the same `y`-value I would like to sort along `x` in increasing value. The values of `x` and `y` can both be negative.

I have tried sorting first along x and then along y with the hope that the x order would remain in tact. Unfortunately this is not the case.

The sorted array of `arr` should be given by

```
sorted_arr = numpy.array([[-2., 8, .1], [-2., 5., .3], [4., 5., .1], [2., 2., .25], [-2., 0., .1], [-1.5, 0., .1], [-1., -3., .2], [1., -3., .1], [5, -4, .1]])
```

Since the actual array is very big I do not want to use `for` loops. How can I sort my array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way could be to use [`np.lexsort`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.lexsort.html) to sort by the second column followed by the first column.

Since this sorts the values in ascending order by default, you could multiply the second column by -1 to "flip" the values so these values are sorted high-to-low instead.

The function returns an array of indices that you can use to reorder the rows of `arr`:

```
>>> arr[np.lexsort((arr[:, 0], -arr[:, 1]))]
array([[-2.  ,  8.  ,  0.1 ],
       [-2.  ,  5.  ,  0.3 ],
       [ 4.  ,  5.  ,  0.1 ],
       [ 2.  ,  2.  ,  0.25],
       [-2.  ,  0.  ,  0.1 ],
       [-1.5 ,  0.  ,  0.1 ],
       [-1.  , -3.  ,  0.2 ],
       [ 1.  , -3.  ,  0.1 ],
       [ 5.  , -4.  ,  0.1 ]])
```

Comment: Slightly more concise: `arr[np.lexsort((arr[:,0], -arr[:,1]))]`